# Configure two gateways on one LAN, use one normally. But fall back to the other when the first one fails. (Linux, Debian Jessie)

Tags: networking, debian, routing, route, debian-jessie

I'm trying to set up a LAN so that there is a main router that routes all outbound (0.0.0.0) traffic to the internet via a DSL link and also hands out IP addresses to clients on the network via DHCP.
But I also want there to be a secondary router on the same network/switch that that has an LTE link to the internet. I want devices on the network to use the LTE router as a fallback gateway when the main DSL gateway goes down or the DSL connection between it and the internet fails.

[See and example config image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovx6S.png)

At the moment clients are given DHCP addresses by 192.168.1.1 in the range 192.168.1.x and each client only has one ethernet port.

I tried to implement the above system by adding setting the LTE gateway to have an IP address of 192.168.10.1 and configuring clients at 192.168.1.x with a virtual interface `eth0:1` with the following settings in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1
    iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.10.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.10.255
    gateway 192.168.10.1
```

With these settings I can ping the router/gateway at 192.168.10.1 but I can't route traffic through it. I have a feeling this has something to do with the default routes set up in the client machine but I haven't found anything that works yet.

*Or, I could be going about this the complete wrong way, any help at all would be great*

Comment: You need a FHRP (First Hop Redundancy Protocol) such as HSRP or VRRP. Configure that on your routers, assign one as the primary, and set preempt so that the other takes over if the primary fails.